# SVN 1.8 defaulting to non-interactive

Tags: windows, svn, cygwin

I'm using the Windows SVN 1.8 command line client that comes with TortoiseSVN through Cygwin. Right now, it doesn't do any interactive prompting because it doesn't see Cygwin as a terminal device. As in the help for `--non-interactive: do no interactive prompting (default is to prompt only if standard input is a terminal device)`. If I pass in `--force-interactive`, the command hangs.

Is there a way that I can make SVN see Cygwin as a terminal device?

NOTE: I edited the question from my original post because I foolishly assumed `--force-interactive` worked in this scenario. I've narrowed it to the root of the problem.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you don't use the Cygwin SVN client?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes, my company is trying to use only a single SVN client. We are using TortoiseSVN for the Windows GUI, and therefore the command line version bundled with it as well.

Comment: Command-line Subversion client bundled with TortoiseSVN is a native Windows client.